# Mantel test permuting values instead of rows?

Tags: permutation-test, cochran-mantel-haenszel

I mistakenly did a Mantel test by permuting the values in a dissimilarity matrix, instead of the rows of the dissimilarity matrix. I've realized that this is not the Mantel test, but I don't understand the underlying distinction.

Can anybody explain why the rows must be permuted instead of the values within the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just realized, but maybe I'll keep this up so if anybody else has the same question, or I can be corrected.

If you permute the rows and columns together, instead of the values, then this conserves the relationships that a point has with itself. For example, permuting a matrix with rows/columns A, B, and C, if you permute the rows/columns, you preserve the relationship that A has with itself.

If you permute the values, then the relationship A has with itself is no longer conserved.